# Apache 2.2 + mod_fastcgi +php-fpm on Debian 6, Error 404 handling

Tags: php, apache, mod-fastcgi

I have a setup with above mentioned. All works fine except for a one problem, for missing .php files I always get a blank page with 'File not found' message(btw with 404 status code). I have ErrorDocument 404 line in my vhost, but looks like it doesn`t take effect in case of FastCGI(for for files not routed into FastCGI it still works). Is there is a way for correct 404 handling in this configuration? Here it is my vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx/yyy/

    <Directory /var/www/xxx/yyy>
            Options FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Options
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/xxx/yyy/php.fastcgi -socket /tmp/php-fpm -pass-header Authorization
    Action php-fpm-yyy /php.fastcgi virtual

    <FilesMatch ".+(php|html)$">
            SetHandler php-fpm-yyy
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorDocument 404 /map.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yyy/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yyy/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```